# What isotope has the highest mass that does not have spontaneous fission

Tags: radiation, isotopes

What is the highest mass isotope that does not undergo spontaneous fission? In deed I assume it would highest atomic number isotope that decays by other processes.

Comment: Do you intend to distinguish between "stable" and "undergoes spontaneous fission"? The largest stable isotope is Pb-208 - but there are larger nuclei that decay through beta capture for example. Not strictly spontaneous fission. Can you confirm what you intend to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the winner is 256m-Es - of all the isotopes that we know of, this is the one with the highest mass that is not known to decay through spontaneous fission. Not sure if it's cheating to use a metastable state for this... it has a half life of 7.6 hours and decays through $\beta^-$ emission.

See [list of nuclides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclides) (it takes some searching and sorting... this is entry number 781 in their table)

If you want the most massive isotope that is not metastable, then 255-Cf is next down on the list: half life of 1.42 hours, beta emitter. Same source, entry 950.

Comment: <Pedantic mode on>: That would be the current winner that we know of, would it not? <Pedantic mode off> Sorry, couldn't resist...

Comment: @JonCuster pedantic input accepted. Answer updated (and expanded... now you can choose if you want to accept a metastable isotope as the answer or not).

Comment: I think the real pedantic point might be that there are nuclei that we puny humans have not seen yet (like those elusive rumors of the island of "stability" out there somewhere) that might have longer lifetimes. On the flip side, I'm perfectly happy with a metastable nucleus as the answer - it seems fitting, actually.

Comment: @JonCuster - sure, that's why I added "that we know of". Happy you're happy!